# Find the range of change number $c=\frac{\text{Im } z}{\text{Re } z}$ if $|z-3-4i|\le 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am working on the following problem:
Find the range of change of the numbers $c=\frac{\text{Im }z}{\text{Re }z}$ if $|z-3-4i|\le 1$

This is what I did:
Letting $z=x+iy$, I can write from $|z-3-4i|\le 1$ $$(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2\le 1$$ From that it can be written $$2\le x\le 4$$ and $$3\le y\le 5$$ Therefore $$\frac{3}{4}\le c\le\frac{5}{2}$$

Is there anything wrong with my work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If we draw two lines from the origin tangent to your circle, what are the agles formed?  What are the tangents of the angles formed?

Comment: @mint The $x$ and $y$ are *not* independent. The actual range of $c$ is a *strict* subset of your range.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Once the value of $x$ is fixed, the value of $y$ is not allowed to vary beyond a certain range restricted by $x$. I have just found the minimum as $\frac{1}{4}(6  - \sqrt{6})$ ,and the maximum as $\frac{1}{4}(6  + \sqrt{6})$ using  the tangent method above.

Comment: One thing to note is that the max value of $c$ can only occur on the _boundary_ of the given region, i.e. where $|z-3-4i|=1$. (Otherwise you can always increase $c$ by increasing the imaginary part of $z$.) The same is true for the min value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a circle centered at $(3,4)$ of radius $1.$

construct the line between the origin and the center of the circle.
Let $\theta$ be the angle that this line forms with the x axis.

$\tan \theta = \frac 43$

Construct the line between the origin and the tangents.

Let $\phi$ be the angles between each tangent and the line to the center of the circle.

$\sin \phi = \frac 15\\
\cos \phi = \sqrt {1-\sin^2\phi} = \frac {\sqrt {24}}{5}\\  
\tan \phi = \frac {\sqrt 6}{12}$

$c = [\tan (\theta - \phi), \tan (\theta + \phi)]$

$\tan (\theta + \phi) = \frac {tan \theta + \tan \phi}{1-\tan\theta \tan\phi} = \frac {48+3\sqrt{6}}{36 - 4\sqrt {6}} = \frac {6+\sqrt 6}{4}\\
\tan (\theta - \phi) = \frac {tan \theta - \tan \phi}{1+\tan\theta \tan\phi} = \frac {48-3\sqrt 6}{36+4\sqrt 6}= \frac {6-\sqrt 6}{4}$

Comment: Proceeding algebraically (by writing $z$ on $|z-3-4i|=1$ parametrically and min-maxing $c$) I get a range of $\frac{3}{2} \left(1\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)=0.88,2.11.$ This doesn't match what you give above.

Comment: @Doug M I got what Semiclassical got, which one is right?

Comment: @Semiclassical dxiv found my error.